# Using regex with Yup to validate full name with extended latin alphabet only and a minimum of 2 words

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, formik, yup

I have a Reactjs-site where I use Formik and Yup to validate fields in the registration flow. Since I don't want to allow Japanese characters or any special characters but only the extended latin alphabet (so that users can use A-Z, a-z but also use e.g. ÅÄÖÛ).

```
.matches(
        /^([A-Za-z\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00f6\u00f8-\u00ff\s]*)$/gi,
            'Name can only contain Latin letters.'
        )
```

This works great, but I also want the user to enter a minimum of at least 2 names. I know you can chain in Yup so i guess another .matches() with some regex in it or some other Yup rule but I can't seem to find excactly what I'm looking for...

Thanks in advance! <3

## Update!

#### This is the answer from Phan that I probably will end up using:###

```
.matches(
    /^([A-Za-z\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00f6\u00f8-\u00ff\s]*)$/gi,
        'Name can only contain Latin letters.'
    )
.matches(/^\s*[\S]+(\s[\S]+)+\s*$/gms, 'Please enter your full name.')
```

#### This is another solution that I found also worked for me:

```
.matches(
    /^([A-Za-z\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00f6\u00f8-\u00ff\s]*)$/g,
    'Name can only contain Latin letters.'
)
.matches(
    /^(?:([A-Za-z\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00f6\u00f8-\u00ff\s]*)) (?:([A-Za-z\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00f6\u00f8-\u00ff\s]*))$/g,
    'Please enter your full name.'
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you have already matched out non-Latin letters, you only need to use the non-space tag `\S` instead of the word tag `\w` for the second validation.

```
.matches(
        /^([A-Za-z\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00f6\u00f8-\u00ff\s]*)$/gi,
            'Name can only contain Latin letters.'
        )
.matches(/^\s*[\S]+(\s[\S]+)+\s*$/gms,'Please enter your full name.')
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Sp6Bhc/1)**

Comment: Hi Phan! Actually it does a little bit the opposite of what I want. The first .matches() works great if I remove the second one, but since I want a full name in that field I want the user to type at least 2 names. Would you how to accomplish that? So just to be clear, right now I ONLY use: .matches(
    /^([A-Za-z\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00f6\u00f8-\u00ff\s]*)$/gi,
    'Name can only contain Latin letters.'
   )


I also edited the original question now so that it's more up to date.

Thanks in advance! / Joel

Comment: @Joel8bitar Ok, I have updated and improved my answer. Please have a look at it.

Comment: Awesome! That actually worked! Thank you! I also used this solution, which also worked, but I don't know which one is better or why:
.matches(/^([A-Za-z\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00f6\u00f8-\u00ff\s]*)$/g, 'Name can only contain Latin letters.')
.matches(/^(?:([A-Za-z\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00f6\u00f8-\u00ff\s]*)) (?:([A-Za-z\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00f6\u00f8-\u00ff\s]*))$/g, 'Please enter your full name')

Comment: @Joel8bitar Of course my solution is better! :) Just try some name with a surname (eg: Alan Olav Walker). Or adding some space before and after a name (eg:      James Bond    ). The other approach appears to be longer but it has less features, due to unnecessary word filters (which has been done earlier).

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the current regex isn't working:

```
/(\w.+\s).+/gi
```

- It matches a word
- followed by any character (1 or more)
- followed by a whitespace character
- followed by any character (1 or more)

Since the input `Åäö` doesn't contain a valid word character (according to regex), it already fails due to the first rule.

`Åäö Jonsson` does not match since it fails the first and second rule as well

`Åäölam Jonsson` does pass the regex, but it is only matched on the following phrase: `lam Jonsson`.

Since you are only interested in detecting if there are any Japanese characters, change the regex to validate the input differently. This regex will test the input and will fail if there are [Japanese characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_writing_system) in the string (

```
/^[^\u4E00-\u9FBF\u3040-\u309f\u30A0-\u30FF]+$/
```

See the regex in action [here](https://regexr.com/5pfb4).

Comment: Hi and thanks! Sorry I also want to make sure the user can't add any special characters or numbers. The first one I use: /^([A-Za-z\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00f6\u00f8-\u00ff\s]*)$/gi does actually work if I remove the other regex I have, so what I need to know now is how to make sure the user enter at least 2 names also.

Comment: Ok, I was confused by the validation message saying "password". In that case, you can follow @Phan Nhat Huy's answer

Comment: Yeah I get it, It was a typing error, sorry about that! Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

The solution as stated will not work for hyphenated names or the poor Irish and Italian folks etc. who have apostrophes in their names. There are likely other little oddities in naming that will need to be added but those are a couple of obvious ones.

I added support for hyphens and apostrophes ... you can do more to restrict where and how many of them appear in the name but this is just indicating they are legal characters.

In addition, the '*' means 0 or more matches and perhaps you meant to use '+' 1 or more matching characters.

```
const latinCharsRegEx = /^([A-Za-z\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00f6\u00f8-\u00ff\s\'\-]*)$/gi;
```